# What is the best way to set specific pattern format and changing just data

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Let's say I have many entries like this in my file:

```
first_db:
  <<: *default
  database: first_db

second_db:
  <<: *default
  database: second_db
```

What is an ellegant way to append new entries to this file with firmly setted format in bash script:

```
{var1}:
  <<: *default
  database: {var1}
```

I'll execute the script directly from command line - not .sh file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understood properly but from the command line you could append by using [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
$ var1=foo 
$ cat >> yourfile<<EOF 
heredoc> ${var1}
heredoc>   <<:*default
heredoc>   database: ${var1}
heredoc> EOF
```

In terms of consistency I would say that @RomanPerekhrest answer is the best:

```
$ printf "%s:\n  <<: *default\n  database: %s\n" "$var1" "$var1" >> inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

> execute the script directly from command line - not .sh file.

As an example of appending one new entry with **`printf`** function:

```
var1="third_db"
printf "%s:\n  <<: *default\n  database: %s\n" "$var1" "$var1" >> inputfile
```

An exemplary `inputfile` contents after appending the new entry:

```
first_db:
  <<: *default
  database: first_db

second_db:
  <<: *default
  database: second_db

third_db:
  <<: *default
  database: third_db
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

***Solution 1st:*** Using EOT cat for Input_file appending.

```
cat <<EOT >> Input_file
{var1}:
  <<: *default
  database: {var1}
EOT
```

OR(Following solution, if you want to use var1 as a variable whose value to be inserted into Input_file)

```
var1="foo";cat <<EOT >> Input_file
${var1}:
  <<: *default
  database: ${var1}
EOT
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using simple echo command.

```
echo "{var1}:
  <<: *default
  database: {var1}" >> Input_file
```

OR(Following solution, if you want to use var1 as a variable whose value to be inserted into Input_file)

```
var1="foo";echo "${var1}:
  <<: *default
  database: ${var1}" >> Input_file
```